# How to define nested routes with module unification turned on

Tags: ember.js

I am new to Ember and am likely making a simple mistake somewhere, but I am having trouble getting nested routes (3 levels of nesting) working in a simple app with module unification turned on, in both ember 3.2.0 and 3.3.0.

(I was able to get the same routes working in another app without module unification.)

In my app, I have module unification turned on by setting the following environment variables in my `.bashrc`:

```
export EMBER_CLI_MODULE_UNIFICATION='true'
export MODULE_UNIFICATION='true'
```

Here are the relevant lines of my `src/router.js`:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('peach', function() {
    this.route('pear', function() {
    });
  });
});
```

Here is `src/ui/routes/peach/index/template.hbs`:

```
peach
{{outlet}}
```

Here is `src/ui/routes/peach/pear/index/template.hbs`:

```
pear
```

Navigating to `http://localhost:4200/peach/pear` results in a blank browser page with the following error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: this._config.collections[specifier.collection] is undefined _checkDefaultType@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:69136:11

TypeError: this._config.collections[specifier.collection] is undefined
```

Why are these routes not working with module unification turned on, and how can I get them working?

Comment: What version of ember and ember-cli are you on?

Comment: @jelhan So far I have tried with ember-cli (and ember-source) 3.2.0 and 3.3.0. In both cases I was able to get it working without module unification, but not with module unification. I can reproduce the problem in a brand new app created with `ember new`, with the above routes and templates added. Node version is 8.11.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have an issue in your route files instead of your template files.

But, as you’ve noticed, module unification is still a work in progress and isn’t ready to be used heavily. We’re all looking forward to it, but for now, unless you want to live on the bleeding edge (which may hurt a decent amount), it may be worth steering clear ...